# CSRF validation failed in Drupal

Tags: firefox, drupal, poster

I'm using a webservice in Drupal 7. If I try to use [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) I get '[CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) validation failed'. Before, I was connected with an administrator account.

I use the Firefox add-in [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/).

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass along the CSRF token in the header of the service request.

To retrieve the token, navigate to:

http://www.example.com/?q=services/session/token

Copy the token to your clipboard.

Then in FireFox poster, using the "Headers" tab, add this name and value:

- Name: X-CSRF-Token
- Value: [paste-the-token-value-here]

Now when you make requests, the token will be passed along correctly with FireFox Poster.

Here's a detailed blog post outlining this topic:

http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/drupal-services-csrf-token-firefox-poster