# Validation failed in WebService

Tags: web-services, drupal, drupal-7

I want to do a Post with 'Advanced REST Client' to get information in Drupal 7 but I get 'CSRF validation failed'.
I have installed drupal 7.4 and the following modules active:  services and services_tools
What's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSRF validation IOS SDK DRUPAL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808442/csrf-validation-ios-sdk-drupal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate: 
[CSRF validation IOS SDK DRUPAL [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808442/csrf-validation-ios-sdk-drupal)
[CSRF validation failed in Drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499125/csrf-validation-failed-in-drupal)

You must review CSRF Validation section in:

[CSRF Validation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2015065)